# AS3 timer.reset();

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer

From everything I've read about the as3 timer.. supposedly the timer.stop() stops the count where it is and will continue where left off when one creates the timer.start(). Also, I have read that timer.reset(), unlike the stop method, brings the timer back to the beginning count so that it would be starting at zero again before hitting the timer.start again... but it doesn't work. I must be missing something really basic  because the below code only stops the count and doesn't reset to zero:

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
var time = 0;
myTimer.start()
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,timerHandle);

function timerHandle(e:TimerEvent){
    txt_time.text = time.toString();
    time++;
}

box_restart.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkforclose);

function checkforclose(event:MouseEvent):void
{                           
    if (event.target.name == "box_restart")
    {   
        trace("this function worked");
        myTimer.reset();
        box_restart.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkforclose);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you understand under 'brings the timer back to the beginning count so that it would be starting at zero again'?
*reset():void - Stops the timer, if it is running, and sets the currentCount property back to 0, like the reset button of a stopwatch.* => so it just sets the PROPERTY back to 0, it doesn't mean that stop() will actually pause your timer while reset() stops it.

Comment: @Sly Raskal - must not be a scoping issue because it came up [object Timer]... any other ideas?

Comment: @Fygo - when I click button (box_restart) the running numbers in the dynamic text box stop but do not go back to 0 even though the code says reset() and not stop() .... any ideas?

Comment: you did not mention anything about your textfield not returning to 0 in your post.  if that is your issue, you need to be more clear.   If it is that you want your textfield to return to 0 when the timer stops, simply set the textfield to 0 in your `checkForClose` event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments about the textfield not returning to 0 when you stop your timer, try the following code.  It should resolve your issue.

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
var time = 0;
myTimer.start()
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,timerHandle);

function timerHandle(e:TimerEvent){
    txt_time.text = time.toString();
    time++;
}

box_restart.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkforclose);

function checkforclose(event:MouseEvent):void
{                           
    if (event.target.name == "box_restart")
    {   
        trace("this function worked");
        myTimer.reset();
        txt_time.text = 0;
        box_restart.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkforclose);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, this is the answer for this question for sure. I had recreated part of a swf that I was having trouble with and was trying to narrow down the problem.. I thought the problem was with the reset but as you've just shown, it is not. When the timer is interupted on the swf I can't get the images the timer is revealing to set back to alpha = 0 and I'm not sure why... atleast I can rule out this reset as a possibility. Thanks again! :) Kristen

Comment: You're welcome! Glad we were able to help you resolve the issue. :)

Comment: @ristenk1 If you are curious, the reason the text field didn't reset before is as follows. You added an event listener for the timer event, which is triggered every time the timer ticks (in your case once every 1000ms). When stop/reset is called the timer does not dispatch an event to tell you it has stopped, and will not trigger your event handler again. Therefore as Anil suggested you should manually handle the fact the timer has reset.

Answer (score 0):

A tweak of the solution from @Anil Natha where you can use the Timer's currentCount property, can manually call the timerHandler from your click handler to keep the updating of txt_time in one place.

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
myTimer.start()
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,timerHandle);

function timerHandle(e:TimerEvent){
    txt_time.text = myTimer.currentCount.toString();
}

box_restart.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkforclose);

function checkforclose(event:MouseEvent):void
{                           
    if (event.target.name == "box_restart")
    {   
        trace("this function worked");
        myTimer.reset();
        timerHandle(null);
        box_restart.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkforclose);
    }
}
```